Smartgit ignore untracked files when pull
Using Smarting(default settings):

Local working tree has untracked files
Standard view
Checking out a new branch
Trying to Pull remote changes fails with error "Working tree has local changes"

However when using the command-line git pull it works without issues.
Any ideas how to disable the check in Smartgit ?
Edit:
"Working tree" view allows you to stash the files while pulling. That could be an intermediate solution.

so you want to out-smart smartgit?

Hehehe nice pun. Yes, the idea is  configure it to be able to fit my intentions
